PyQt6 Не устанавливается иконка окна
В PyQt6 я пытаюсь установить иконку для окна, да еще и чтобы после компиляции в nuitka оно сохранялось. Я использую этот код:
def get_resource_path(self):
    try:
        resource_name = "ico.ico" 
        resource_path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "resources", "ico.ico"))
        resource_path = resource_path.replace("\\", "/")
        self.append_log(f"{resource_path}")

        if not os.path.exists(resource_path):
            self.append_log(f"Ресурс {resource_name} не найден по пути: {resource_path}")
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Ресурс {resource_name} не найден по пути: {resource_path}")
        return resource_path
    except:
        return os.path.join('resources', resource_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Windows11Launcher()
    icon_path = window.get_resource_path()
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon_path))
    window.setWindowTitle("myapp")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Но почему-то иконка не сохраняется после компиляции.

из python в exe

И как вы её делаете, почему этого нет в вопросе?

так сказано "после компиляции в nuitka". Загуглите что это
